# I can't get my php encryption to work

Tags: php, function, encryption, salt

The script is surpose to encrypt a password so that it is much harder to use rainbowtables on it and there for people cannot hack the server so easily, but i cant seem to get it to work so i hope one of you can help me.

```
<?php

function enc($string){
    $salt = "randomsalt";
    $hash = sha1(md5($salt.$string)) . $md5($string) . sha1(md5(md5($string)));
    return $hash;   
}

echo enc('password');

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? What does it do, and what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: **Hashing != encryption**

Comment: SHA1 and MD5 are both broken.  Use bcrypt.

Comment: You must use a different salt for each user.

Comment: double\triple hashing makes it less secure not more

Comment: possible duplicate of [How long should my password salt be, and is SHA-256 good enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191690/how-long-should-my-password-salt-be-and-is-sha-256-good-enough) AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords and ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$md5( $string)
```

breaks your code. Remove the $

You should use something like bcrypt and different salts for all your users.

Comment: Thank you mate. I did not see that you wrote. i'm new here, hehe :)

Answer (score 1):

Listen to the comments, but you also have a typo:

`$md5($string)` needs to be `md5($string)` (it's not a variable, it shouldn't have a `$` in front of it).

It's true that you're not encrypting here, but that's just a nomenclature issue (you're hashing it, which is what you want to do)... however, your salt probably shouldn't be a fixed string... it should vary by user if you really want a strong hash. There's a lot more to say on this subject (`md5` and `SHA1` aren't the best hash algorithms for passwords as there are too many rainbow tables for both and they're too fast to execute), but you can read up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536584/non-random-salt-for-password-hashes/536756#536756) and [here for bcrypt info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php).